# What's the appropriate SE website for a question about finding a chat application?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation, superuser

I'm looking to see what platform would be the best for what my professor is looking for. He wants a chat application where students can communicate with both the TA's (like myself) and the professors from their computers, but not with each other.

Would this question be appropriate on Stack Overflow, or should I look at maybe Super User?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is one that asks for recommendations.

As such it is off topic to all Stack Exchange sites - Stack Overflow and SuperUser included.

It falls under the "Chatty and open ended" category.

Comment: Okay. Should I try one of the chat channels for this?

Comment: You _could_, though I am not sure what the rules on chat are.

Comment: @SetSlapShot the upside of chat is that you can ask about pretty much whatever you want there. The downside is that not many people use it, and good luck finding someone there who actually has an answer to your question.